# Github workflow does not read variables from environments

Tags: github-actions, environment

Following is my simple github workflow. It is intended to print an environment variable.

```
name: verify

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  read_env_variables:
    environment: build 
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, onprem_dae, docker ]
    steps:
      - name: cat on branch file
        run: |
          echo ${{ env.SOME_VARIABLE }}
```

I have created an environment named "build". In this environment, I have an environment variable named `SOME_VARIABLE` set to *xyz*.

When the workflow is triggered, I expected to echo value *xyz* but actual value is "". Is there something missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue here is related to the syntax.

To use the `${{ env.SOME_VARIABLE }}` syntax, you need to set an env variable at the workflow, job or step level.

**Here is an example:**

```yaml
name: Environment Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  WORKFLOW_VARIABLE: WORKFLOW

jobs:

  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      JOB_VARIABLE: JOB
    steps:
      - name: Run Commands with various variables
        if: ${{ env.WORKFLOW_VARIABLE == 'WORKFLOW' }}
        env:
          STEP_VARIABLE: STEP
        run: |
          echo "Hello World"
          echo "This is the $WORKFLOW_VARIABLE environment variable"
          echo "This is the $JOB_VARIABLE environment variable"
          echo "This is the $STEP_VARIABLE environment variable"
```

---

Now, if you want to use the **environment secrets for deployment**, [as explained here on the Github Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment), the syntax would be different using the `job_id.environment` [as you are already using following this doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment).

Here is an example:

```yaml
  job4:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: build
    steps:
      - name: Show repo env secret
        run: |
          echo ${{ secrets.REPO_ENV_SECRET }}
```

Note that **this variable is a secret**, therefore you won't be able to see it through an echo command on the step (it will show `***`)

---

Here is the workflow I used to validate all this implementation if you want to take a look:

- [workflow yaml file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/10-environment-workflow.yml)
- [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/7297762218)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Yes. It does show `***`.  In the larger solution, value set github environments is expected to be written to a binaary.  Does using `${{ secret.KEY_NAME }}`.  If echo returns `***`, which expression is used to get the secret in plain form ?

Comment: If the value is a secret, there is no way to display it on the Github Action runner display window (for security reasons). However, if the value isn't a secret and you want to show it somewhere, it would be adequated to use and env variable in the workflow instead (that would not be encrypted).

Comment: Just to be clear - Variable in context is a secret per environment. In github, I have created environments named "dev", "test" in github. Variable `REPO_ENV_VAR` is configured to different values in the mentioned environments. So, these are variables are seen as secrets always in github. Hence, they should be read using `${{ secrets.<var_name> }}`. Is the understanding correct?

Comment: When you create an environment in the repository settings it will work as you explained (with `secrets.<var_name>`). However, when you create a workflow, job or step environment variable in the workflow, you will access the value using `env.<var_name>`. Both can be named environment variables, that mat be confusing as the syntax and the context are different.

Comment: It is confusing until tried and understood with examples. It still gets vague until validated with developers familiar with the system.

Comment: It is confusing until tried and understood with examples. It still gets vague until validated with developers familiar with the system.

Answer (score 2):

When using GitHub environments (GitHub repo > Settings > Environments), you can set:

- `Environment secrets`
- `Environment variables`

`Environment secrets` are accessed using the standard [`secrets context`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#secrets-context).

`Environment variables` are accessed using the [`vars context`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context).

### Example CD workflow with Environment variable

```yaml
name: cd

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        required: true
        type: string
        description: 'The environment to deploy to'

env:
  SHELL: /bin/bash

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}

    steps:
    - name: Verify environment
      run : |
        echo "Environment variable TEST_VAR: ${{ vars.TEST_VAR }}"
```

If you attempt to access the environment variable with `${{ env.TEST_VAR }}`, it will fail.